# Using a dataframe to construct an other in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, python-3.5

As the title says, I've been trying to build a Pandas DataFrame from an other df using a for loop and calculating new columns with the last one built.

So far, I've tried :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10))
df.columns = [10]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10))
df1.columns = [10]

steps = np.linspace(10,1,10,dtype = int)
```

This works:

```
for i in steps:
    print(i)
    df[i-1] = df[i].apply(lambda a: a-1)
```

But when I try building df and df1 at the same time like so :

```
for i in steps:
    print(i)
    df[i-1] = df[i].apply(lambda a: a-df1[i])
    df1[i-1] = df1[i].apply(lambda a: a-1)
```

It returns a lot of gibberish + the line :

```
 ValueError : Wrong number of items passed 10, placement implies 1
```

In this example, I am well aware that I could build *df1* first and build *df* after. But it returns the same error if I try :

```
for i in steps:
    print(i)
    df[i-1] = df[i].apply(lambda a: a-df1[i])
    df1[i-1] = df1[i].apply(lambda a: a-df[i])
```

Which is what i really need in the end.

Any help is much appreciated,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apply` is trying to apply a function along an axis that you specify. It can be 0 (applying the function to each column) or 1 (applying the function to each row). Per default, it is applying the function to the columns. In your first example:

```
for i in steps:
    print(i)
    df[i-1] = df[i].apply(lambda a: a-1)
```

Each column is looped because of your `for` loop, and your function `.apply` removes 1 to the entire column. You can see `a` as being your entire column. It is exactly the same as the following:

```
for i in steps:
    print(i)
    df[i - 1] = df[i] - 1
```

A way you can see `.apply` is with the following. Assuming I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4))
```

`df.sum()` and `df.apply(lambda a: np.sum(a))` yields exactly the same result. It is just a simple example, but you can do more powerful calculations if needed.

Note that `.apply` is not the fastest method, so try to avoid it if you can.

An example where `apply` would be useful is if you have a function `some_fct()` defined that takes `int` or `float` as arguments and you would like to apply it to the elements of a dataframe column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

def some_fct(x):
    return math.sin(x) / x

np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2))
```

Obviously, `some_fct(df[0])` would not work as the function takes `int` or `float` as arguments. `df[0]` is a `Series`. However, using the `apply` method, you could apply your function to the elements of `df[0]` that are themselves floats.

```
df[0].apply(lambda x: some_fct(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights ! if dropping the .apply() is faster and easier, what's the use of apply ? Also, what is the most common/accepted way of doing this task ?

Comment: I am not an expert on the apply, but an example would be to apply a special function that does not take as arguments the object you are trying to pass. I will edit my answer and you can have a look.

Comment: I see ! Thanks a lot for tanking the time to answer !

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I just need to drop the .apply !

Example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10))
df.columns = [10]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10))
df1.columns = [10]

steps = np.linspace(10,1,10,dtype = int)

for i in steps:
    print(i)
    df[i-1] = df[i] - df1[i]
    df1[i-1] = df1[i] + df[i]
```

It does exactly what it should !

I don't have enough knowledge about python, I cannot explain why

```
pd.DataFrame().apply()
```

will not use what was out of itself.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  This solution you've posted here gives a very different answer than the solution you posted in your original post, where you wrote: "This works: ...". In your original post, after the computation you said works, `df` displays a diagonal of zeros, with negative numbers in the upper triangle and positive numbers in the lower triangle.  In the solution you've posted here, however, `df` displays a range of positive and negative numbers, from `-288` to `144`.  It might be useful to actually post your desired output in the text of your original post.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for wondering ! The thing here is that the two functions used as examples are differents ! I may not have been enough clear but my problem was only to make such a loop give an output and not an error !